# Unique field in Microsoft Dynamics CRMv4

Tags: dynamics-crm, field, dynamics-crm-4

Is there a way in Microsoft Dynamics CRMv4 to force values of a field to be unique without having to program a plug in?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in feature for enforcing uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of options here.

**1) Use Duplicate Detection**
Depending on your needs, duplicate detection would work with the proper configuration.  Just set the duplicate detection rules on the field that you want to be unique, and it will prompt you to change that field's value before saving the record.
**NOTE: This will not PREVENT you from saving a duplicate, but it will prompt you and let you change the data presave.  You can ignore the duplicate detection and just create a new record with the same values anyway**

**2) Use an existing Custom Workflow Activity that you can find out on the web**
There are a ton of Auto number solutions available for free online.  You then configure the entity, field, and format of your auto number, and then boom, you have a code-free, uniqueness generator.

Please mark as answer if solves your issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a unique index on the entity's table. Custom table indexes always have been supported customizations. Your users will only need to get used to somewhat technical error messages when trying to create duplicate data.

Comment: How do I create a unique index on the entity's table?

Comment: You can use SQL Server Management Studio for that purpose.

Comment: note: This only works with the On-Prem version as you must connect directly-to, and modify the Dynamics Database.